# Django - how to create membership models with foreign keys and manytomanyfield

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a django membership models with 2 model classes: Target and Group.

I want to have targets attributable to certain groups, but also to be able to query which targets are in which group. This is what I have so far and I am able to see that "targets" is a field of Group but it shows up as empty in the query set when I access Group.objects.get(pk=1) through a variable. I also want both groups and targets to be attributable to certain users.

Here are my models, what am I doing wrong? I've tried doing this a few different ways so far:

```
class Target(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Target First name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Target last name')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, default='email@example.com')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email


class Group(models.Model):
    group_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Group name')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    targets = models.ManyToManyField(Target, related_name='targets', blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both the ForeignKey and the ManyToManyField. If you just want each target to be in a single group, keep the FK but drop the M2M. Then from your group you can do `mygroup.target_set.all()` to get the list of targets in that group.